# Exchange Get-MailboxFolderStatistics FolderSize to MB

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

Morning folks, and what a sad day it is to be British.

Anyway, I'm trying to get `MailboxFolderStatistics`'s `FolderSize` to MB.

The following line:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics Joe.Bloggs |
    Where-Object { $_.FolderPath -ne "/Deletions" } |
    Select-Object FolderPath, @{ N = "FolderSize (MB)"; E = { $_.FolderSize.ToMB() } }
```

works fine when I'm using Exchange Management Shell.

But if I'm using a remote PS session into one of my Exchange boxes, I don't get anything for `FolderSize`.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you break this down to individual commands, does the first one (`Get-MailboxFolderStatistics Joe.Bloggs`) give you a result ?

Comment: Hi Sodawillow

It does yes. If I do
  Get-mailboxFolderStatistics Joe.Bloggs | select FolderPath, Foldersize 
I get the folder path and FolderSize in "2.364 MB (2,478,818 bytes) " format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the Exchange Management Shell you run on the server includes a type named `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize` that gets converted to a `System.String` through remoting. The former exposes a `ToMB()` method, the latter does not.

I have written a workaround, but maybe there is a simpler and/or prettier method :

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics Joe.Bloggs |
    Where-Object { $_.FolderPath -ne "/Deletions" } |
    Select-Object FolderPath, @{
        N = "FolderSize (MB)";
        E = {
            "{0:N2}" -f ((($_.FolderSize -replace "[0-9\.]+ [A-Z]* \(([0-9,]+) bytes\)","`$1") -replace ",","") / 1MB)
        }
    }
```

This uses a regular expression to turn the ugly string (example : `3.712 KB (3,801 bytes)`) into a usable number. On my system `,` is not a valid digit grouping symbol so I had to remove it from the string, too.

Comment: You sir, are a hero. 
Thank you. Works a treat

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following lines to get the $_.FolderSize represented in [decimals]

```
Select-Object  @{
N = "FS_MB";
        E = {
            [math]::round( ([decimal](($_.FolderSize -replace "[0-9\.]+ [A-Z]* \(([0-9,]+) bytes\)","`$1") -replace ",","") / 1MB),2)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when looking at folder sizes there is desire to sort them by size descending. To achieve this we need to know the FolderAndSubfolderSize in Bytes and store that in a `bigint` property as opposed to `System.String`. *It's not rocket science to convert Bytes to Kb,Mb,Gb so I won't go into that here.*

**In-line syntax** for dynamically adding a new property FolderAndSubfolderSizeBytes (*I've used backticks to split over several lines for legibility only*)

```
Get-EXOMailbox -Identity user.name@domain.com`
| Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics `
| Select Name,FolderAndSubfolderSize,@{`
    name="FolderAndSubfolderSizeBytes";`
    expression={((($_.FolderAndSubfolderSize -replace '^(.*\()(.*)(\sbytes\))$','$2').Replace(',','')) -as [bigint])}} `
| Sort-Object -Property FolderAndSubfolderSizeBytes -Descending | ft
```

**Long-hand** add new properties to variable object for later re-use

```
$mb = Get-EXOMailbox -Identity user.name@domain.com | Get-EXOMailboxFolderStatistics
foreach ($folder in $mb) {
    $folder | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FolderSizeBytes -NotePropertyValue ((($folder.FolderSize -replace '^(.*\()(.*)(\sbytes\))$','$2').Replace(',','')) -as [bigint])
    $folder | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FolderAndSubfolderSizeBytes -NotePropertyValue ((($folder.FolderAndSubfolderSize -replace '^(.*\()(.*)(\sbytes\))$','$2').Replace(',','')) -as [bigint])
}
$mb | Select Name,FolderPath,FolderAndSubfolderSize,FolderAndSubfolderSizeBytes | Sort-Object -Property FolderAndSubfolderSizeBytes -Descending | ft
```